# 19.10 High CPU usage when watching video, Intel Whiskey Lake, UHD 620

Tags: drivers, video, intel-graphics

I have a brand new 7th gen Lenovo x1 Carbon with a Whiskey Lake i7-8565U processor, Intel UHD Graphics 620 (with 16gb ram in case it is relevant). I am running stock Ubuntu 19.10.

I was watching a video in VLC and noticed after a while, things started stuttering and eventually everything slowed to a crawl, I believe due to the CPU usage being so high the computer heated up and started heavily throttling. I am finding the same issue with the standard 'totem/Videos' app as well. Manually setting the video acceleration in VLC to 'VA-API video decoder' didn't help.

With htop I realized just watching the video was taking 60% CPU! This is quite remarkable, just to watch a 25fps 720p mp4.

After some research I thought I had to install intel-media-driver, but realized it is already installed, so I am a bit surprised by how poor the video acceleration is? Is there anything that can be done to remedy this? I'm not sure if it matters if `vainfo` tells me the driver is the i965 driver for Coffee Lake.

`vainfo` shows the following:

```
libva info: VA-API version 1.5.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_4
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 1.5 (libva 2.5.0)
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Coffee Lake - 2.3.0
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSliceLP
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264MultiviewHigh      : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointEncPicture
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP8Version0_3          : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileHEVCMain10             : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVP9Profile0            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileVP9Profile2            : VAEntrypointVLD
```

Comment: Ok, for what it's worth, `mpv` actually plays the exact same video at the same time point at only 6% cpu, so it looks like video acceleration *does* work, but not in VLC or totem. My question still stands though if I should be updating my driver for Whiskey Lake or not somehow? In case it is helpful, I ran `mpv --vo=vaapi --hwdec=vaapi <filename>` but actually didn't even need to, it is just accelerated by default.